# Where can I write methods to be used in a partial? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, view

I'm using a partial to render each row in a somewhat complex table (venues have many events and events have many attendees).

I have a method I'd like to use to determine the rowspan of each row dynamically depending on the number of attendees. I have the method, but I'm not sure where to house it to make it accessible to my partial... it didn't work in my helper file and I'm not entirely convinced that's where its supposed to go.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your method should work from as a helper method. Have you verified that it is not being called?

Dropping a debugger in the method might help you track down what's going on. Maybe it's getting called and just not doing what you think it should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are filling out the form for Venues, any methods to be used in this form or its partials need to be placed in the venues_controller.

Comment: I'm not filling out any forms, just generating table rows. Would I still write them in my venues_controller?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: Can you name the view file in which you are generating the above mentioned table?

Comment: app/views/venues/index.html.erb

Comment: You will have to use jquery for it. Your custom method needs to be written in the venues_controller itself. Enable this method to respond to js. You will also have to create a js file in the app/views/venues folder with the same name as that of your custom method.